# How to monitor NIFI Flow File Storage and Content Storage threshold

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there a way to monitor NIFI Flow File and Content File Storage?
And trigger alert(Email/Slack) If it reaches the threshold(80%).

I want monitor stats shown under- `Menu-> Cluster: JVM, FlowFile Storage, Content Storage`

Can Nifi reporting task help to achieve this? If yes, please share instructions.

We had a NIFI downtime because FlowFile storage was used completely. We want to perform proactive monitoring to avoid this scenario again.
Any suggestions/pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System Diagnostics REST endpoint (/system-diagnostics) even from NiFi (with InvokeHttp for example) to get at the storage usage. Also I wrote up [NIFI-8239](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-8239) to add such metrics to the appropriate reporting tasks.

Comment: Thank you. Look forward for new feature implementation.